# Whitelist traffic to mysql from a kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Cloud MySQL instance which allows traffic only from whitelisted IPs. How do I determine which IP I need to add to the ruleset to allow traffic from my Kubernetes service?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use the Cloud SQL Proxy in a sidecar pattern. This adds an additional container into the pod with your application that allows for traffic to be passed to Cloud SQL.

You can find instructions for setting it up [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine). (It says it's for GKE, but the principles are the same)

If you prefer something a little more hands on, [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gmemegen) codelab will walk you through taking an app from local to on a Kubernetes Cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Google Cloud Platform, so my solution was to add the Google Compute Engine VM instance External IP to the whitelist.